# S1000 Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed in Intellij only

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, intellij-idea, jdbc

When using

- IntelliJ 2018.2.1 with driver MySQL Connector/J ver. 5.1.46
- DataGrip 2018.2.1 with driver MySQL Connector/J ver. 5.1.46

When I execute a call to a stored procedure, I get an error message

```
[S1000] Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
```

A simple stored procedure for testing

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE test1()
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'THIS IS A TEST TEXT';
    END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

The call

```
CALL test1();
```

The output

[image: The error message]

[image: The query result]

**NOTE:** I don't get the issue when using console.

Comment: Which version of MySQL Connector/J are you using?

Comment: mysql-5.7.17-winx64

Comment: That is your MySQL version, I asked about the MySQL Connector/J version (the version of the MySQL JDBC driver you use in IntelliJ).

Comment: 5.1.64 in intellij settings.Don't know which one datagrip uses.

Comment: There is no version 5.1.64, did you mean 5.1.46?

Comment: Yea, sorry for the typo. Its "MySQL Connection/J ver. 5.1.46"

Comment: MySQL procedures execution is not yet specifically supported. Only Oracle and Postgres, see https://blog.jetbrains.com/datagrip/2018/07/26/datagrip-2018-2/#running.

Comment: I've actually filled a separate issue for this. You can track the: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-6889.